HVAC return duct size
Is 18x12 filter size return large enough? 773 sq ft house. I'm getting quotes to replace furnace and condenser with heat pump. Several quoters have said 2 ton & that existing 18x12 is too small. I was going to cut larger the existing hole which was originally cut thru cmu structural wall. Not a task I'm looking forward too. I'm looking at larger return vents that id need to buy & most have grills that block up to 50% of airflow. Air handler manufacturers must consider that when specifying return size. My 18x12 has no grill. So. I think it can safely be 50% smaller then manufacturers specify.

I'm not sure this question is answerable without more detail about your system as a whole. Filter (plenum) size is usually much larger than the return duct itself, to reduce flow resistance through the filter medium. In my 1992 home, the vertical return duct is 10x20, while the filter is 20x24. That's a 240% upsize.  Please revise to provide more information and photos if you can.

Generally the minimum size of the return is dictated by the units design and how much CFM of air the fan can move, not the size of the home.  You need to get the info on return size from the manufacturer of the HVAC unit.  All this stuff should be part of the new install package.

Generally 2 sq. ft. of filter per ton of cooling. If new air handler has a ECM you will be happy you enlarged it.

https://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/article/designing-return-filter-grille-boxes

That should be in your answer. Please take the [tour] and see [answer].

Last contractor actually said he wasn't sure of size needed & will get back to me. 2 days later he said "I have an air duct calculator and a 12 x 18 opening will move 1400 CFM. A 2 ton system is 800 CFM. If you add a filter and a front grille, it drops to 900 CFM. It is fine for a 2 ton system but too small for a 3 ton system."

That was not my complete post. Somehow tabbing to next line is adding my comment & three edit attempts accomplished nothing.

It did it again. Last line of my post today was to be: your thoughts?

@PaulMars, tabbing on the internet moves you between fields. The Enter key creates line breaks, but there are no line breaks in comments.

@PaulMars, I'm not sure what you intended with that comment. If you would like to provide your own answer, do so in the appropriate box.

This AH can support internal air filter. In that case could i keep the return hole 18x12?
